# Ember.Select: Wrong selected value when content is set asynchronously

Tags: ember.js

Here's the problem in jsbin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/bahuvusa/29/edit

When I have a select such as this:

```
{{view Ember.Select
  contentBinding="items"
  optionValuePath="content.value"
  optionLabelPath="content.caption"
  value=value
}}
```

Where `items` is set in the route as an `PromiseArray` and the data looks like this:

```
[
  {value: 1, caption: "one"},
  {value: 2, caption: "two"},
  {value: 3, caption: "three"}
]
```

And I have the value set in a controller:

```
value: function() {
  return 2;
}.property()
```

When the template renders I would like to see the **second** element selected, but instead the value is set to `undefined` (see the jsbin).

Is there a way to make this work? (without making the elements an ember-data model and using `selectionBinding`)

### Update

I ended up using the `afterModel` hook and returning the promise from it: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/bahuvusa/40/edit

Comment: Probably related to issues [1333](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1333) and [1405](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1405)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments in your post, I took some of the code from the last comment in this ticket github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1333 and did some small changes, this how the code looks like now: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/bahuvusa/30/edit

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! My example was too contrived, I've updated the jsbin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/bahuvusa/29/edit. In this case the controller already has another model, so I can't use the `model` hook..

Comment: I see, looks like your problem has to do with the issues you put in the comments, why don't you try any of the solutions given there ?, I used the one in the last comment in this issue https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1333 and it worked.

Comment: I used almost the same code as the link in the previous comment http://emberjs.jsbin.com/bahuvusa/30/edit

Comment: At first this seemed like a hack, but I think it's the simplest solution here. Thanks, `fanta`! You can update your answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the selection to the model or a property that you want to update dynamically based on that selection change event. So, assign a model or collection to the the `selection` property, and you can also set the `prompt` in there:

```
{{view Ember.Select
  contentBinding="content"
  optionValuePath="content.value"
  optionLabelPath="content.caption"
  selection=model.value
  prompt="Set the prompt"
  value=value
}}
```

Example JSBin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/bahuvusa/27/edit

This is pretty much the same concept/pattern across the board with the handlebars helpers. Hope that comes in handy!

Comment: Thanks, Matthew! The thing is, I want the 2nd element to be selected when the template is first rendered (hence the `value=value` and the property in IndexController)

Comment: @whatthewhat Well, it's async so you need to supply the default value. It either needs to be on the model or a property on the controller. The code is behaving correctly for me... You can remove the prompt to see the first rendered value is 2.